# Googlemaps API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT with no API Key

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an app that makes use of the googlemaps API. I'm not using any API key as I'm performing requests like `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit` (shown in one of the Google examples). Unfortunately, lately it keeps giving the following error:

```
{
    "error_message": "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
    "routes": [],
    "status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Even by adding a key I create as a parameter to the GET request (i.e., `&key=blahblah`), the result is always the same. Does this mean my I.P. is blocked by Google?

What can I do to get it back to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the key it means that that the limit for the account where the key has been created for has been reached.

When you don't use a key it means that the limit for the IP of your server has been reached.

**What you can do:** 
wait until tomorrow or request the service from [clientside](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)